# How to rotate a child opposite of its parent in BGE?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, parent

What I want to do is, rotate the parent-object (while playing the game), and its child (which will revolve around the parent) to rotate in the direction opposite to its parent:

[image: original]

This is the original position.

[image: rotated]

This is when I rotate the parent(selected)

[image]

This is what I want(But while playing in BGE, either by python script or logic bricks

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible without Python and Logic bricks. 
As far as I see, you want the child to keep its original orientation. This can be done by vertex parenting. You need to add a single vertex to the mesh of the parent on the location where the child is. Then parent the child to the vertex.